# Run Slickgrid's filter in resverse

Tags: filter, filtering, slickgrid

I am using slickgrid and I have rows that represent groups of rows. Using slickgrid's default filter function it filters through my grid data in order from index **0** up to index **n**. Is there a way to run the filter in reverse? Meaning start my filter at index **n** and go down to index **0**?

I'm looking to store the group rows I want to display in an array as the filter runs through the grid data. This way when I come to a grouping row it will always show if there are items in that group within the filter. But hide grouping rows if no items in that group are within the filter.

For example if I have the following rows:

1. **-------Dogs-------**
2. Golden retriever
3. Corgi
4. **-------Cats-------**
5. Calico
6. Maine coon

The "Dogs" and "Cats" rows are group rows. If I filter on the letter **"c"** for instance the grid should look like this:

1. **-------Dogs-------**
2. Corgi
3. **-------Cats-------**
4. Calico

Filtering in only the pets with "c" in their name. But also filtering in the **"Dogs"** grouping row even though it doesn't have the letter "c" in it.

Also if I filter on **"m"** the grid should look like this:

4. **-------Cats-------**
5. Maine coon

Hiding the **"Dogs"** row because there are no items under it that match the filter.

The reason I'm asking if the filter can be run in reverse is because I've seen this problem posted here before and the answer was run through the array using your own filter, tagging the items in the array you want displayed in the array, and then running slickgrid's filter function against that tag. This means traversing the array at a minimum of 2 times. If it was possible to run slickgrid's filter in reverse it could be accomplished in one traversal. Speeding things up significantly.

Comment: maybe call the DataView [sort](https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid/blob/master/slick.dataview.js#L169) in descending without rendering the grid and do the filtering from there? However doing that will reverse the entire dataset when you're ready to re-render, to counter that though you could save the previous sort, then re-apply original sort after the data is filtered. By looking at the code, there's no array copy, so whatever you do on the dataset will be applied on the end result, I mean the sort.

Comment: I assume you're talking about this using a DataView. It looks like there will be two phases internal to the DataView: ```getFilteredAndPagedItems()``` and ```extractGroups()```. Wouldn't you need to combine these into a single loop to achieve what you are suggesting? If so, this would be pretty specific to your need. Overall, I'm not sure I exactly understand what your problem is.